# Python datetime simplify 24hour time and total dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I am using Python 3.8.0 on windows 64

I have a long string with 24hr times which I want to sum total. See code below for logic description. Can I simplify using `datetime` module?

With existing code it may happen that hrs_finish <= hrs_start. How can I check and add 24hrs to hrs_finish if this happens? See below for current script:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

#String extracted from pdf using PyPDF2
pdfstring = 'Utilities Dd Tmp No/s0417 937 023Equipment / Additional Charges\nCrew SpeciÞc Instructions\nBrisbane1/23 Darnick St, Underwood  QLD  4119\nPhone: 07 3841  7773  Fax: 07 3841 2229\nBerkley Heath\n8:0017:450:30Yes\n141Yes\nYes\nTyson Trindall\n8:3015:300:30Yes\nYes\nYes\nNaser Bin Khaleel\n10:3015:300:30Yes\nYes\nYes\nBernard Macinnis\n15:3017:450:00Yes\nYes\nYes\nTsz Ching Suen\n15:3017:450:00Yes\nYes\nYes\nClient Not On Site - Authorisation Signature\n CLIENT NOT ON SITE'

#Finding hours from pdfstring using regex pattern of digits and ':' to read and locate
regexhours = re.compile(r'(\d\d*):(\d\d)(\d\d):(\d\d)(\d\d*):(\d\d)')
hours_sublist = regexhours.findall(pdfstring)

#converts listed strings into integers so can subtract
hrs1 = [list(map(int, x)) for x in hours_sublist]

#creates dataframe using pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(hrs1)
print(df)

#How can I check hrs_finish <= hrs_start?
hrs_start = df[0]*60+df[1]
hrs_finish = df[2]*60+df[3]

#calculating total hours = Finish - Start times
df_total = (hrs_finish - hrs_start)/60
print(df_total)

#Total hours worked
Hours_worked = sum(df_total)
print(Hours_worked)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go about it like this:

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df[0]*60 + df[1], unit='m')
df['finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df[2]*60 + df[3], unit='m')

(df['finish'] - df['start']).sum()
# Timedelta('1 days 02:15:00')
```

Or you can get just hours:

```
(df['finish'] - df['start']).sum() / pd.Timedelta('1 hour')
# 26.25
```

**EDIT**

To get your 24 hour diff solved, you can use:

```
(df['finish'] + (df['finish'] < df['start']).astype('timedelta64[D]') - df['start']).sum()
```